# Merging two dataframes - union of IDs, "ANY" over values

Tags: r, dataframe, array-merge

I have two tables `A` and `B`, with the following 3 columns/variables:

1. `id`: A unique patient identifier (char strings)
2. `cancer`: Binary variable for whether cancer was present (`0`=no, `1`=yes)
3. `hiv`: Binary variable indicating whether HIV was present (`0`=no, `1`=yes)

The two tables may have different sets of `id`'s but they have the same 3 columns.

What I want to do is to merge them such that the merged table contains the following:

1. `id`: The entire set of unique patient identifiers from both `A` and `B` (i.e. the union)
2. `cancer`: `1` if the patient had `cancer=1` in either `A` or `B`. `0` otherwise, including if missing.
3. `hiv`: Same as `cancer` except for `hiv`

I'm not sure what's the best way to go about doing this. Base R, tidyverse or data.table examples are all acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want to `join` them. I would think, with the same columns, you may want to append them:

```
library(tidyverse)

A %>%
bind_rows(B) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(cancer = max(cancer, na.rm = T),
          hiv = max(cancer, na.rm = T) %>%
ungroup()
```